# Java.Swing Изменение размеров компонентов при "прилипании" окна в современных ОС

Tags: java, swing

Суть проблемы заключается в том, что при изменении размеров окна путем перетягивания его границ, внутренние компоненты без каких-либо ошибок меняют свои размеры, подстраиваясь под новый размер окна. Однако разворачиваясь в полноэкранный режим, или при "прилипании" к краю экрана (Функция современных ОС) масштаб компонентов сохраняется таким же, как при последнем изменении размера обычным способом. А возвращение окна в исходный размер разворачивает компоненты для полноэкранного режима.

Основной класс:

```
public class Window extends JFrame implements ComponentListener
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    WorldCamera screenArea;
    SidePanel sideBarArea;

    Window(int width, int height)
    {   
        addComponentListener(this);

        setSize(width, height);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setResizable(true);
        setVisible(true);

        this.loadScreen(width, height);
    } 

    void loadScreen(int width, int height)
    {
        screenArea = new GameWorldCamera();
        sideBarArea = new SidePanel();

        screenArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((width / 6 * 5) - 20, height - 50));
        sideBarArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((width / 6) - 10, height - 50));

        screenArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        sideBarArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        this.add(screenArea);
        this.add(sideBarArea);
        System.out.println("Now width: " + width + ", height: " + height);
    }

    void unloadScreen()
    {
        try
        {
            this.remove(ScreenArea);
            this.remove(sideBarArea);
        }
        catch(NullPointerException Ex)
        {
            System.out.println(Ex);
        }
    }
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) 
    {
        System.out.println("Now x:" + this.getWidth() + " y:" + this.getHeight());
        try
        {
            screenArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((this.getWidth() / 6 * 5) - 20, this.getHeight() - 50));
            screenArea.printSize();
            sideBarArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((this.getWidth() / 6) - 10, this.getHeight() - 50));
            sideBarArea.printSize();

        }
        catch(NullPointerException Ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Компоненты:

```
class WorldCamera extends JPanel
{
WorldCamera()
    {
        System.out.println("camera created");
    }

    public void printSize()
    {
        System.out.println("Camera x:" + this.getWidth() + " y:" + this.getHeight());
    }
}

class SidePanel extends JPanel
{
    SidePanel()
    {
        System.out.println("side panel created");
    }

    public void printSize()
    {
        System.out.println("Side panel x:" + this.getWidth() + " y:" + this.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148950/how-to-detect-jframe-window-minimize-and-maximize-events
Тело сообщения должно содержать не менее 30 символов; вы ввели 0.

Comment: Благодарю! Странно что сам не нашел, буду внимательнее в следующий раз! Правда, про тело сообщения я не совсем понял.

Comment: Подсказка получилась замечательной, но помогла только на половину. Нажатие на кнопку "развернуть" и перетаскивание окна к верхней границе экрана срабатывает как нужно, однако, перетаскивание его к правой или левой границе вызывает все ту же ошибку.

Comment: Нахожусь в поисках ответа, пока решить вопрос средствами WindowListener, WindowStateListener и ComponentListener удалось только от части, компоненты приложения все еще масштабируются неверно, когда окно перетягиваешь к правой или к левой границе экрана.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился использованием -

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(Component)
```

Метод обновляет содержимое компонента по его текущим параметрам.[Здесь можно посмотреть на конкретный пример!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628121/how-can-i-refresh-or-reload-the-jframe) SimAllllll спасибо за хорошую ссылку!

Comment: Надеюсь, что поможет тем, кто столкнулся с решение подобных вопросов. Спасибо!